# Tagbar plugin works in vim but not neovim

Tags: vim, neovim, tagbar

I have the [tagbar](https://github.com/majutsushi/tagbar) plugin working perfectly in vim but no tags are displayed in neovim.

When I use `TagbarDebug` from within both, I can see that the ctags output is fine when run from vim, but from neovim, `tagbardebug.log.ctags_out` just has the following line:

```
^[[31;01m'^[[39;00m^[[31;01m/usr/local/bin/ctags-f---format=2--excmd=pattern--fields=nksSaf--extra=--file-scope=yes--sort=no--append=no-V--language-force=python--python-kinds=icfmv/var/folders/_z/tz5sb8jd6mj41gj2gn8qvhhr0000gn/T/nvimoU8Oxr/1.py^[[39;00m^[[31;01m'^[[39;00m
```

From `tagbardebug.log`, I can see that ctags is called slightly differently between the two. From within vim, the log has:

```
Calling shell to execute: "('/usr/local/bin/ctags' '-f' '-' '--format=2' '--excmd=pattern' '--fields=nksSaf' '--extra=' '--file-scope=yes' '--sort=no' '--append=no' '-V' '--language-force=python' '--python-kinds=icfmv' '/var/folders/_z/tz5sb8jd6mj41gj2gn8qvhhr0000gn/T/v0jhgoR/4.py') >/var/folders/_z/tz5sb8jd6mj41gj2gn8qvhhr0000gn/T/v0jhgoR/5 2>&1"
```

but from neovim, the equivalent line is:

```
Executing command: "'/Users/owen/miniconda3/bin/xonsh' '-c' ''/usr/local/bin/ctags' '-f' '-' '--format=2' '--excmd=pattern' '--fields=nksSaf' '--extra=' '--file-scope=yes' '--sort=no' '--append=no' '-V' '--language-force=python' '--python-kinds=icfmv' '/var/folders/_z/tz5..."
```

The difference appears to be how ctags is being called - vim calls it directly but neovim calls the shell executable and passes the -c argument. However, if I run the command used by neovim from the command line, it works fine.

I've tried setting `tagbar_ctags_bin`, but that made no difference.

Any clues as to where else I need to dig?

Comment: I suspect that vim is _also_ calling the shell, it's just that neovim is being explicit about it. vim says: "_calling shell_ to execute [blah blah blah]". neovim says: "Executing command [your weird shell] -c [blah blah blah]". Is it possible vim is calling via a different shell? How would we tell?

Comment: I did wonder whether xonsh might be the issue, but it hadn't occurred to me that vim might be 'doing its own thing' I might try changing my default shell to bash and see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that `xonsh` makes some assumptions about being connected to a terminal, which is true in terminal Vim but not gVim nor Neovim (which invokes commands using pipes).

Try setting `shell*` options to their default values:

```
:set shell& shellcmdflag& shellpipe& shellquote& shellredir& shellxquote& shellxescape&
```

(Or simply remove the lines in your config that set those options.)

> The difference appears to be how ctags is being called - vim calls it directly but neovim calls the shell executable and passes the -c argument

No, that's just a difference in log output. Vim also uses the 'shell' option and 'shellcmdflag' options (which is hinted by its log message: *Calling shell to execute...*).

Comment: Fantastic! That's the issue! Adding a line in init.vim to set the shell as bash has solved it. Thank you kindly